# Dynamics CRM 2011 - Custom form with duplicate checking

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to create a custom opportunity form which will almost mirror the out of box one but would like to add a section for checking duplicate records.

The overall goal is that when the form is filled out that section should populate with possible duplicate records to merger with.

I know there is out of box duplicate checking but not sure if it can be implemented this way.

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to build a Web Resource in an IFrame that uses javascript to call the RetrieveDuplicatesRequest message.  Here's a link that should help:

http://crm-edinburgh.com/2011/08/crm-sdk-using-detect-duplicates-settings-in-code/

This assumes that you already have Duplicate Detection set up and running.

Comment: Very nice Josh. Let me give this a whirl then give you an accepted answer after some testing but this looks like what I needed. Thanks!